# Типы, полностью доступные во время выполнения (reifiable types)

Tags: java, generics, терминология, типы

Что значит - `типы, полностью доступные во время выполнения (reifiable types)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html)

> A reifiable type is a type whose type information is fully available at runtime. This includes primitives, non-generic types, raw types, and invocations of unbound wildcards.
>
> Non-reifiable types are types where information has been removed at compile-time by type erasure — invocations of generic types that are not defined as unbounded wildcards. A non-reifiable type does not have all of its information available at runtime. Examples of non-reifiable types are `List<String>` and `List<Number>`; the `JVM` cannot tell the difference between these types at runtime. As shown in Restrictions on Generics, there are certain situations where non-reifiable types cannot be used: in an `instanceof` expression, for example, or as an element in an array.

`Reifiable` тип это тип информация о котором полностью доступна во время выполнения программы. Такие типы включают примитивы, не обобщенные типы, сырые типы(`List list = new LinkedList();`) и вызовы `unbound wildcards` (например `List<?> list`).

`Non-reifiable` типы это типы где информация была удалена во время компиляции механизмом `стирания типов` - вызовы обобщенных типов которые *не определены* как unbounded wildcards. У `Non-reifiable` типов вся эта информация *не доступна* во время работы программы. Примеры таких типов это `List<String>` и `List<Number>`; виртуальная машина Java не может определить разницу между такими типами во время выполнения программы. Как показано в "Ограничения Обобщений", существуют определенные ситуации когда `non-reifiable` типы не могут быть использованы: например c выражением `instanceof` или как элемент массива.